# FastAPI endpoint not receiving post data

Tags: python, api, fastapi

Here is the endpoint, at the moment it is the only endpoint because I'm following the FastAPI tutorial. the print statement only prints  `{}` .

```
@app.post('/contact', response_model=schemas.Contact)
def create_contact(contact: schemas.ContactCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    print(contact)
    return crud.create_contact(db=db, contact=contact)
```

This is the contents of the `schema.py` file

```
class ContactBase(BaseModel):
    name: str
    email: str
    subject: str

class ContactCreate(BaseModel):
    pass

class Contact(ContactBase):
    id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

and this is the error that is being throw by the endpoint

> response -> subject
> none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)

and this is the post data

```
{"name":"bailey","email":"a@a.com","subject":"kjgjhkh"}
```

I'm not too sure whats going on because I've followed the SQL tutorial on the FastAPI docs and it all looks correct to me. It seems the issue is the endpoint isn't receiving the data from the post request but I'm really not sure why, and it is definitely hitting the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

upon closer inspection the `ContactCreate` class is inheriting the wrong class, changed it to the `ContactBase` class and now it works.